# How to fix OutputStream and the like not writing the value "0"?

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a system that will write out x amount of bytes to a file. I've discovered though, that whenever you try to write a byte with the value of "0", it won't write anything for it, and, apparently, doesn't write anything after it either.

So, I NEED some way to write out all this data, and I can't have it stopping every time it encounters a 0. Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 24, 24, 24, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0};
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Test.txt", true);
    out.write(data, 0, data.length);
    out.close();
}
```

This will end up writing each byte successfully until it reached the first 0, at index 4. Then it just stops.

Here is the output:
[image: Output]

Edit: Solved

Comment: What makes you think it stops writing at index 4? Your code works as expected for me.

Comment: @Chall yes it works for me also.

Comment: I've tried it numerous times. Does the fact that I'm running it on Linux have any effect?

Comment: How are you verifying this? Looking at the `hexdump`, I see `18 18 18 05 00 05 05 05 00 00 00`, which is correct.

Comment: Remember that you are writing bytes. How are you reading the file, to come to the conclusion that it's not being written correctly? If you see it with a text editor most probably it will try to show it as ASCII and show a bunch of garbage characters. Use a hex editor or viewer like @August suggests.

Comment: Oh, I never even though to try and read it using the InputStream. I just assumed. But even then, shouldn't it show the other ones that aren't 0? Like, the 5's that come after the first 0?

Comment: It all depends on what the viewer you are using does with the actual content of the file when it tries to render it. Did you look at it in hex yet?

Comment: I've re-read it using an InputStream, and it does in fact show the rest of them.

Comment: @Chall so seems issue resolved.

Comment: Just want to say, thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does write a 0 byte to the file.

It is *Eclipse* that does not display anything after the first 0 byte. Presumably, this is a bug in Eclipse.